# Getting a type error and I can't find out why

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

This code was working previously but now is giving me issues.

```
def stringsAreFun():
string1 = input("Enter a String you want to modify: ") #stores the user imput to string1 variable
stringLength = len(string1) #stores stringlen to a variable for future, repitive calls
print("The length is ", stringLength)
print("The first character is " + string1[0]
+ " and the last character is " + string1[stringLength - 1])
listString = list[string1]
if stringLength >= 6:
    #creates a list of characters from string1 because strings are immuntable in python
    #http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm
    listString[stringLength - 1] = 'C'
    listString[stringLength - 2] = 'B'
    listString[stringLength - 3] = 'A'
    print(''.join(listString)) #joins the list(x) into a string to be printed
    #http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm
if stringLength >= 6:
    listString[0] = 'X'
    listString[1] = 'Y'
    listString[2] = 'Z'
    print(''.join(listString))

if stringLength >= 2 & stringLength <= 5:
    listString[0] = '1'
    print(''.join(listString))
if stringLength >= 2 & stringLength <= 5:
    listString[stringLength - 1] = '0'
    print(''.join(listString))

if stringLength % 2 == 0:
    print("The length of the string is an even number!")

else:
    print("The length of the string is an odd number")
```

I m getting this output:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: In the future, add information about which line the exception happened. It means less guessing and faster answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

> ```
> listString = list[string1]
> ```

doesn't do what you want.

```
listString = list(string1)
```

Comment: wow thanks you. I guess this is what happens when you have been staring at code for 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `list(string1)`, not `list[string1]`. The latter is subscripting (with `[]`) the `type` object `list`, which produces the error you saw.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you meant to convert `string1` to `list` , when you tried this line -

```
listString = list[string1]
```

The issue is that `list()` is a built-in type, you need to call it passing the `string1` as argument. Example -

```
listString = list(string1)
```